Smallest sum not obtainable using a subset of elements in array greater than the minimum element
I am solving a variation of the missing coin sum problem, modified to be as follows:

You have n coins with positive integer values. What is the smallest
sum greater than the minimum coin in the array you cannot create using a subset of the coins?
Constraints:
$1 \le n \le 2 \cdot 10^5$
$1 \le x_i \le 10^9$
Input:
2 9 1 2 7
Output:
6
Input:
5 7 6 9
Output: 8

For the original problem (where the minimum sum does not have to be at least the minimum element in the array), there is a greedy algorithm that sorts the array and tracks the minimum sum not obtainable so far, adding successive elements to that sum provided that adding each element does not create a "gap" in the range of elements possible. In other words, an invariant is being maintained that for the value of $s$ at index $i$, all values until and including $s - 1$ can be constructed using elements up to index $i - 1$. If the $a[i]$ is greater than $s$, then $s$ cannot be constructed using a subset of the elements because:

$a[i]$ is itself greater than $s$, so it cannot be used alone nor added to any other subset of previous elements as that would be greater than the element itself.
Since $s$ is 1 more than the sum of $a[1..i - 1]$, $s$ cannot be created by any subset of those elements.

In that case, the value of $s$ is returned, since $s$ is the smallest value in the "gap" that is being constructed by the new element $a[i]$. If $a[i]$ is less than or equal to $s$, that shows that every element from 1 to and including $s$ can be created and that the new minimum unobtainable sum is the $s + a[i]$:

If $a[i] = s$, then $s$ is obtainable using $a[i]$ itself.
For all values $[s + 1, s + a[i])$, their values can be obtained by adding $a[i]$ to one of the previous subset sums. Adding $a[i]$ extends the range of sums and maintains the invariant.

For example in the first case, the algorithm runs as follows:

set $s = 1$
$a[i] = 1$, $1 \le 1$, so $s = 2$
$a[i] = 2$, $2 \le 2$, so $s = 4$
$a[i] = 2$, $2 \le 4$, so $s = 6$
$a[i] = 7$, $7 \not\le 6$, so return our value of $s$ as $6$.

This works in the first case, but does not in the second case, as the initial $s$ cannot be set to 1 (it has to be greater than the minimum element of 5 for our answer). I thought about setting it to the minimum element + 1, 6, but this would not work as the algorithm would assume that all values prior to 6 are possible to create, which is not true in this case. i.e

set $s = 6$
$a[i] = 5, 5 \le 6, s = 11$ which is already incorrect.

This is not the correct approach. How can I change my approach/algorithm entirely to find the correct minimum unobtainable sum?

What does "using a subset of the coins that is greater than the minimum coin in the array" mean?  What does it mean for a subset to be greater than a coin?  The two are not comparable objects.  You can compare two numbers, but not a set and a physical object.  Please [edit] your post to clarify the problem statement.

I don't understand the greedy algorithm.  Can you describe it in pseudocode?  I don't understand what $s$ represents.  How do you tell whether it creates a "gap"?  I don't understand what is the "first case" and "second case".

Have you tried creating a dynamic programming algorithm?  See https://cs.stackexchange.com/tags/dynamic-programming/info for a general approach.

@D.W. I've edited the question, hopefully it makes more sense. It was meant to say the "minimum unobtainable sum .. that is greater than the minimum coin". $s$ represents the minimum sum not obtainable by any subset of coins at an index $i$, following the loop invariant that all elements up to and including $s - 1$ can be created using some subset in $a[1..i - 1]$. https://stackoverflow.com/a/21073903/6525260 has a good explanation of the algorithm as well.

Regarding dynamic programming, I haven't looked too deeply into it. I'm aware the original problem has a DP solution, though to tell the truth my knowledge of the topic isn't advanced enough to come up with one myself (yet).

If we omit the constraint "greater than the minimum coin in the array", either the problem is trivial (if there is no coin with value 1, then the answer is 1) or the problem is identical to your problem (if there is a coin with value 1, then the problem is identical to your problem), so I can't didn't understand the argument about why you need a very different algorithm.  But I didn't look into the details so maybe I have missed something.

@D.W. I get that, I describe that trivial greedy algorithm in the question. My question was to find how to solve this with that additional constraint (of the answer being greater than the minimum coin). From what it seems, this doesn't seem possible without going back to the dynamic programming solution. Was just wondering if a simple modification to the original greedy algorithm could account for this change as well. In particular, could you clarify why the problem is exactly the same? I don't see why that follows, e.g with an example like {5, 6, 7, 9} and the answer 8.

There is a straightforward solution using dynamic programming.  In particular, the pseudo-polynomial time algorithm for subset sum finds, for each $s$, whether there is a subset of coins that sum to $s$.  You can then scan that array to find the first $s$ such that the answer is "no".
